# page redirect form classic asp to aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am trying to redirect existing classic asp page to .aspx page. In my application I have sfcRecInspedt.asp which is classic asp page. I changed that in ASP.net keeping name same now I do have sfcRecInspedt.aspx and sfcRecInspedt.aspx.cs.

How I will change my code so that if user click on New intend of directed to classic asp page it should goes to sfcRecInspedt.aspx page?

Please find below code from where I am redirecting to classic asp page.

```
<td width=60%>
                    &nbsp;
                    <td colspan=10 align="right">
                        <%lparam="lAdd=Add &lfromdate=" & lfromdate & "&ltodate=" & ltodate & "&lplantid=" & lplantid%>

                         <a href="JavaScript:GotoNewWindow('sfcRecInspedt.asp?<%=lparam%>',<%=clng(Session("WIDTH"))%>,<%=clng(Session("HEIGHT"))%>);">
                         <img src="/images/newe.gif" border="0" alt="New" valign="middle"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">New</font></a>
```

Comment: Look at the answer I have posted. It will do what you need.

Comment: depending on where it (sfcRecInspedt.aspx ) is located you should just be able to modify the URL to new page:
[<a href="JavaScript:GotoNewWindow('sfcRecInspedt.aspx.....]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following under just before the closing `configuration` tag in your web config file. Replace the path and destination with appropriate paths.

```
   <location path="folderName/sfcRecInspedt.asp">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://foo.com/sfcRecInspedt.aspx"
       httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />        
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question this seems like overkill (?).
I think #sony921 is just trying to get his link to go to the new page.

Comment: Changing code is one option, but when there is a potential for many pages needing redirection then its best to redirect from config. Plus code changes can be minimized with config approach. But it depends on the situation.

Comment: I would go with the config approach since it easy and very simple Vs changing it in code. Just use the config I have mentioned and you should be good to go. I am guessing you are working on a classic ASP application?